# Using multidimensional array in HTML select?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a search engine for my online shop orders. They have status groups, and instead of making a `select` for each group, I was hoping to make a `optgroup` for them.

This:

```
<?php
if($_GET) {
    print_r($_GET);
}
?>
<form>
    <select name="status[]" class="form-control selectpicker" multiple data-actions-box="true" data-width="480px">
        <optgroup label="WAREHOUSE" data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger">
            <option value="[WAREHOUSE][For processing]">For processing</option>
            <option value="[WAREHOUSE][For calling]">For calling</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="OFFICE" data-icon="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger">
            <option value="[OFFICE][For request]">For request</option>
            <option value="[OFFICE][Requested]">Requested</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [status] => Array
        (
            [0] => [WAREHOUSE][For processing]
            [1] => [WAREHOUSE][For calling]
            [2] => [WAREHOUSE][For request]
            [3] => [WAREHOUSE][Requested]
        )

)
```

I was hoping to return:

```
Array
(
    [status] => Array
        (
            [WAREHOUSE] => For processing
            [WAREHOUSE] => For calling
            [OFFICE] => For request
            [OFFICE] => Requested
        )

)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what if you change `name="status[]"` to `name="status"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the output rendered as it plain text and it is expected as it is the value of the option you set.
to achieve your approach you need to create a custom function to remap the coming data to your needs .
in your case you can try this

```
foreach($status as $item){
    $arrayKey = strstr($item, ']', true).']';
    $arrayValue = str_replace(['[',']'],'',strstr($item, ']'));
    $newArray[][$arrayKey] = $arrayValue;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: Yeah, if I remove the second bracelets (`[...]`), I can do `foreach($_GET['status'] as $item) { preg_match('/\[(.*?)\](.*)/s', $item, $matches); $status[$matches[1]][] = $matches[2]; }`, but I tought that it can be done without PHP parsing... :-)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want. You shouldn't use select for the form. Use checkbox instead.